# Using JSON and creating markers for Android Maps API load time

Tags: android, arrays, json, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I m implementing google maps in my android project which retrieves JSON data from a URL to draw markers in the map,also it has a search option with autocomplete addresses of google places API here is my codes.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    LocationAddress add=new LocationAddress();
    DashboardActivity dObj=new DashboardActivity();

    public void onClickHome (View v)
    {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    class MyInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

        private final View myContentsView;

        MyInfoWindowAdapter(){
            myContentsView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_contents, null);
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
            displayView(arg0);
            return myContentsView;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {

            return null;
        }

        public void displayView(Marker arg0) {

            String[] contents=arg0.getTitle().split("@");
            String title=contents[0];
            String address=contents[1];

            ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(title);
            ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.snippet)).setText(address);

        }

    }

   private static final String LOG_TAG = "myApp";
   private static final String SERVICE_URL = "JSON_DATA_URL";
   private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
   private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
   private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

    //------------ make your specific key ------------
    private static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyDKUpzHkox5q5-pcNYmRS-UT7izEvd6WtQ";

   protected GoogleMap map;
   private GoogleApiClient client;
   TextView latlongLocation;
   Marker marker;
   Button clear;
   AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
       setUpMapIfNeeded();
       setTitleFromActivityLabel(R.id.title_text);

       client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

       autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
       autoCompView.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item));
       autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

       clear=(Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);
       clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
               autoCompView.setText("");
           }
       });

   }


    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        String str = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try
        {

         //   removeSearchMarker();
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(str, 3);
            if (addresses != null && !addresses.equals(""))
                search(addresses);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
        ArrayList<String> resultList = null;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
            sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
            sb.append("&language" + "fa");
            sb.append("&components=country:af");
            sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());

            System.out.println("URL: "+url);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
            return resultList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
            return resultList;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");
            resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
               System.out.println(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
                System.out.println("============================================================");
                resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
        }

        return resultList;
    }

    class GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {
        private ArrayList<String> resultList;

        public GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return resultList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int index) {
            return resultList.get(index);
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter filter = new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    if (constraint != null) {
                        resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());
                        filterResults.values = resultList;
                        filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                    }
                    return filterResults;
                }

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                    if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    }
                }
            };
            return filter;
        }
    }

   protected void search(List<Address> addresses) {

   Address address = (Address) addresses.get(0);
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());

   // String  addressText = String.format("%s, %s", address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "", address.getCountryName());

    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
    latlongLocation.setText("Latitude:" + address.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + address.getLongitude());
   // map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MyInfoWindowAdapter());
   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       setUpMapIfNeeded();
   }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        map=null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }


   private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
       if (map == null) {
           map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                   .getMap();
           if (map != null) {
               setUpMap();
           }
       }
   }

   private void setUpMap() {
       LatLng origin = new LatLng(34.520299, 69.179912);
       CameraUpdate panToOrigin = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(origin);
       map.moveCamera(panToOrigin);
       map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13), 400, null);
       map.getUiSettings();
       map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
       map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
       map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
       map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MyInfoWindowAdapter());

       new Thread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               try {
                   retrieveLocations();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot retrive locations", e);
                   return;
               }
           }
       }).start();
   }

   protected void retrieveLocations() throws IOException {
       HttpURLConnection conn = null;
       final StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
       try {
           URL url = new URL(SERVICE_URL);
           conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
           InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

           int read;
           char[] buff = new char[1024];
           while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
               json.append(buff, 0, read);
           }
       } catch (IOException e) {
           Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to service", e);
           throw new IOException("Error connecting to service", e);
       } finally {
           if (conn != null) {
               conn.disconnect();
           }
       }

       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               try {
                   createMarkersFromJson(json.toString());
               } catch (JSONException e) {
                   Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing JSON", e);
               }
           }
       });
   }

   void createMarkersFromJson(String json) throws JSONException {

       JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
       for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
           JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
           String address=add.getAddressFromLocation(jsonObj.getDouble("geolat"), jsonObj.getDouble("geolng"), getApplicationContext());

          String date=jsonObj.getString("posted_date");
           SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
           Date testDate=null;
           try{
               testDate=sdf.parse(date);
           }catch (Exception ex){
               ex.printStackTrace();
           }
           sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy  HH:mm aa");
           date=sdf.format(testDate);
           map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                           .title(address.toString()+"@"+date)
                           .position(new LatLng(jsonObj.getDouble("geolat"), jsonObj.getDouble("geolng")
                           ))
                           .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon3))
           );

       }
   }

    public void setTitleFromActivityLabel (int textViewId)
    {
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById (textViewId);
        if (tv != null) tv.setText (getTitle ());
    }

}
```

These codes are working properly to draw markers from json data in maps but the problem is that when I start this activity it takes too much time to display the map and markers and during this time everything is like frozen i can't go back or home and if i click many times on any screan components its crashing the application.
 the number of json records which createMarkersFromJson method is looping through for creating markers maybe like 40-50 records and there are possibilities to extend. So my question is what is the reason of this problem and is there any other way to display markers in the map fast without crashing the application?.

I should mention that i m new to android development, Any help would be much appreciated. thank you in advance!

Comment: I see that you are still using `getMap()`. You're implementing your code using deprecated functions. I suggest going through the [Android Google Maps Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start#step_1_download_android_studio), there you'll see that [getMapAsync()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html#public-methods) is the new version. You can also browse around the community to see similar posts. Cheers!

Comment: thank you for your answer @McAwesomville , I would be glad  if you could provide me any example related to this.

Comment: The quickstart I linked has the official sample codes.

Comment: I found the issue @McAwesomville thanks alot

Comment: You should post an answer then accept it as the correct one then. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Android guidelines](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) I believe you should use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for "retrieveLocations" instead of creating a thread on your own to [connect to a network.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html).

Comment: +1 Simple and on the spot answer. Well done. It'd also be good if you can link the ***Android guidelines*** you mentioned in your post

Comment: thank you for your answer @Amit I will follow the guidelines and try to implement AsyncTask , if you could provide me the link of any example which retrieves location information from server and display as markers in this way you mentioned would be awesome.

Comment: I used AsyncTask but it still takes the same time to load markers @Amit

Comment: What did you use AsyncTask for ? Are you using Runnable for runOnUiThread as per the code you posted earlier? Also as far as I understand using AsyncTask is not going to make it faster but its a good practice.

Comment: What was the issue ?